# Building WIX project with Team Build

Tags: tfs, wix, tfsbuild, wix3.5

I am using WIX to create setup.msi for my project on a TFS Server. I added the WIX project to solution.

Just to begin with, before I added WIX project to my solution, Team Build was outputing all project assembiles to my drop folder which was perfectly fine.

But now once I have added the installer project, i want Team Build only to output my .msi and not the project assemblies to my drop folder.

I think I am missing some configuration setting. Can you please suggest as what might be wrong here?

Kindly advise.

The Team build is outputing the .msi as well as all the project asemblies

Comment: NO one to suggest any solution?? :( Fellow TFSBuilders I'd really appreciate your kind guidance!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your build is working fine. You just want your Build Drop folder to contain the MSI and no other files.

If using Team Build 2008, the way to achieve this would be to add a new `<Target>` to your `TFSBuild.proj` file that overrides the built-in `CoreDropBuild` target.

```
<Target Name="CoreDropBuild"
    Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true' and '$(SkipDropBuild)'!='true' "
    DependsOnTargets="$(CoreDropBuildDependsOn)" > 

    <!-- Copy output MSI files -->
    <CreateItem Include="$(BinariesRoot)\**\*.msi" >
        <Output ItemName="FilesToCopy" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem> 

    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
        DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy ->'$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        ContinueOnError="true" /> 

</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to accomplish this other than to turn off copying to the drop location and then writing your own custom process to copy just the files you want.  Follow Grant's solution for Team Build 2008 or 2010.  For TFS2012 you will need create a custom template that contains this custom file copy.